# Trouble with aligning drop down parent menu item with the rest of the site menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, css-float

I am having trouble with the menu on this site. Below is all css coding to the offending menu. You can see it live here. [website](http://www.youthsquad.org/) All I am trying to do is get the word Futsal to align with the rest of menu.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to spend time helping me to resolve this issue.

```
PAGES NAVIGATION
#pages { width: 922px; background-image: url(images/nav-bg.png); height: 55px; float: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; display: block; color: #FFF !important;}

#pages ul li:hover a:link, #pages ul li:hover a:visited { background-color: #5a5a59; color: #FFF !important;}

#pages ul { margin-top: 5px; list-style-image: none; position:relative; }

#pages li a:link, #pages li a:visited { height:35px; background-image: url(images/nav-line.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right; display: block; float: left; padding: 15px 20px 0px 20px; color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;}

#pages li a:hover { background-image: url(images/nav-bg2.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; color: #FFF;}

DROPDOWN MENU

.nav, .nav * {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}

.nav ul { position:absolute; top:-999em; }

.nav li { float:left; position:relative; z-index:99; font-size:12px; height: 44px !important; border: none !important;}

.nav a { display:block;}

.nav ul li { width: 100%;}

.nav li:hover ul, ul.nav li.sfHover ul { left:0px; top:45px;}

.nav li:hover li ul, .nav li.sfHover li ul { top:-999em;}

.nav li li:hover ul, ul.nav li li.sfHover ul { left:240px; top:-5px;}

.nav li:hover ul, .nav li li:hover ul { top: -999em; }

.nav li li { display: block; padding: 0px; background-image: url(images/pages-bg2.png); float: left; height: auto !important;}

.nav li:hover { height: auto !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;}

.nav li li a:link, .nav li li a:visited { width: 180px; display: block; padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px !important; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important; height: auto !important; color: #FFF !important; float: left; background-color: #5a5a59; background-image: none !important; }

.nav li li a:hover { background-color: #5a5a59; color: #FFF !important; background-image: url(images/nav-bg.png) !important;}

CURRENT PAGE

.current_page_item a:link { color: #555555 !important; }

.current_page_item a:hover { color: #FFFFFF !important; }

.current_page_item { color: #555555 !important; }



CATEGORIES NAVIGATION

#categories { height: 37px; background-image: url(images/categories-bg.gif); width: 950px; display:none; }

#categories ul { float: left; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; margin-top: 10px; height: 27px; padding-left: 10px; }

#categories li { float: left; display: block; list-style-image: none; list-style: none; height: 27px !important; }

#categories li:hover, #categories li.sfHover { background-color: #FFF; background-image: url(images/categories-button-right.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right; }

#categories li a:link, #categories li a:visited { color: #FFF; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; display: block; height: 25px; padding-top: 2px; font-size: 11px; float: left; }

#categories li a:hover, #categories li:hover a:link, #categories li.sfHover a { background-image: url(images/categories-button-left.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left; color: #585858; }

DROPDOWN MENU

#nav2 li { z-index: 98; }

#nav2 li:hover ul, ul#nav2 li.sfHover ul { top:17px; left: -10px; }

#nav2 li li a:link, #nav2 li li a:visited { color: #585858 !important; background-color: #FFF; padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px !important; }

#nav2 li li { height: 38px !important; }

#nav2 li li a:hover { background-color: #f4f4f4; background-image: none !important; color: #585858 !important; }

#nav2 li li:hover ul, ul#nav2 li li.sfHover ul { left:230px !important; top:-6px !important; }
```

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)...

Comment: I would suggest you position your dropdown menu with absolute positioning to take it out from the document flow.

Comment: .nav, .nav * {position:absolute; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;} Just added this and it just made everything is big pile of jumble. I tried adding padding rules to the above as well with no improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add href="" to second li anchor tag. Then do this:

```
#navigation ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
}
```

You were overriding your absolute position with #pages ul {position: relative}

EDIT:

```
.nav li > ul {
    display: none;
}
#pages ul {
    float: right;
}
#navigation ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
}
.nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

And don't forget to replace `<a>Futsal</a>` with `<a href="">Futsal</a>`, that is the reason it went to the top. If you don't want that "a" to be clicked add `<a href="javascript:void(0)">Futsal</a>`

Comment: Nice thank you very much, That fixed the menu expanding all the way to the right. Any wisdom on how to get the main menu to align right?

Comment: Lol well i definitely misspoke. I don't want the menu to actually float to the right side although you completely provided code to do that ;)  I am trying to find a CSS rule that will allow me to adjust the word futsal without messing up the rest of the menu. I am using wordpress and it wont allow me to add the code you told me to add above to fix the hyperlink. I understand what you are saying but without manually editing dynamic code. I am not sure how to accomplish this. Also manually editing it would defeat the end users ease of use I believe.

Comment: I think i got it, by adding # in the url string it stays on that page without refreshing. You are awesome man and thanks for the help.